# add_filter not works in ajax

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, ajax, actions

I edited my woocommerce loop products with **remove_action** and **add_action** functions. And create ajax infinite scroll.

I created woocommerce.php and put all my action functions to it. And called **woocommerce.php**

Here is woocommerce.php:

```
<?php 
if (is_shop() || is_archive()) {

    # Remove result count
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'woocommerce_result_count', 20);

    # Remove image href
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_link_open', 10);

    # Remove price
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_price', 10);

    # Remove add to cart
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);

    # Remove image
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail', 10);

    function call_thumbnail($size = 'resim_boyutu') {
        global $post, $woocommerce;

        if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
            $output = get_the_post_thumbnail($post->ID, $size);
        } else {
            $output = wc_placeholder_img($size);
        }
        return $output;
    }

    function feed_image() {
        ?>
        <div class="urun-resmi col-xl-6 col-md-5 col-sm-5">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">
                <?php echo call_thumbnail('shop_thumbnail'); ?>
            </a>
            <?php
            global $post;
            $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_tag');
            if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                    $echos[] = '<a href="' . get_term_link($term->term_id) . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
                }
                echo '<div class="feed-etiket"> Etiketler: ';
                print implode(', ', $echos);
                echo '</div>';
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    <?php }
    add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'feed_image', 10);

    # Remove title
    remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);

    function product_title() {
        global $post;?>
        <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
            <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="feed-item-baslik"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>
            <?php

            $terms = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'product_cat');
            if ($terms && !is_wp_error($terms)):
                if (!empty($terms)) {
                    echo '<a class="feed-kategori" href="' . get_term_link($terms[0]) . '">' . $terms[0]->name . '</a>';
                }?>
            <?php endif;?>
        </div>
    <?php }
    add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'product_title', 10);

    # Add to cart and preview
    function feed_titles() {?>
        <footer class="col-xl-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 sol-border">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_price();?>
                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_rating();?>
                </div>

                <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 sepet-col">
                    <div class="sepete-ekle">
                        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="incele">Preview</a>
                        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart();?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
    <?php }
    add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'feed_titles');

    # Remove rating
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_rating', 5);
}
?>
```

Here is ajax function:

```
function infinite_scroll_handler(){
    global $post, $product, $woocommerce;


    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );

    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 2; 
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    $woo = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $woo->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $woo->have_posts() ) {
            $woo->the_post();
            get_template_part('woocommerce/content', 'product');
        }       
    }

    die;
} 
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'infinite_scroll_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'infinite_scroll_handler');
```

It works good. But the posts from ajax are not seems true. Because my remove_action and add_action functions not applying them. It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: What actions and filters did you use?

Comment: Sory. Edited my question. Check please.

Comment: So `get_template_part('woocommerce/content', 'product');` is loading `woocommerce/content-product.php` from within your theme. Do you have that file? And does that file have the necessary `do_action()` calls?

Comment: Yes. content-product.php has all do_action() calls.

Comment: I just noticed in your first block of code: `if (is_shop() || is_archive()) {`. Neither of those will be true in an AJAX context.

Comment: It is not about **if (is_shop() || is_archive()) {** because i tried wtihout them.